# "Touch" current file in emacs

Tags: emacs

Im emacs, I want to run "touch" on the file referenced by the current buffer (specifically want to change the modification time). I use [guard](https://github.com/guard/guard) to run some tests after files are changed, but sometimes I want to invoke it manually. I don't care about running the actual shell utility touch so long as mtime is set.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of that question. I don't want to have the file saved, I just want the mtime of the file to be updated (hence the need for touch, not the pure emacs solution of @jtahlborn)

Comment: I wish people would not close questions without reading them carefully.  This is actually a good question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Of course, this assumes that you have a command named `touch` on your path.

```
(defun touch ()
     "updates mtime on the file for the current buffer"
     (interactive)
     (shell-command (concat "touch " (shell-quote-argument (buffer-file-name))))
     (clear-visited-file-modtime))
```

In dired-mode there is a touch command bound by default to `T`. That command isn't so easy to use though because it prompts the user for a timestamp. I suppose that's very general, but it isn't a very convenient way to do what is typically intended by "touch."

Comment: beautiful, I wasn't sure how to get the filename into the command.

Comment: What if the buffer name has spaces in it?  Or ends with "; rm -rf /"?  I would suggest using `(shell-quote-argument (buffer-file-name))`

Comment: If it has spaces in it then some quotes will do -- I'll add that. If you're naming your files with "; rm -rf /" then you deserve what you get! :) Reminds me of this: http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: I *think* adding shell-quote-argument solves both issues, oh whoops just saw @nemo's edit.

Comment: There is one thing I had to add in order to make this less annoying. `(clear-visited-file-modtime)` after the shell command execution to _update_ Emacs buffer with the new state of the file.

Comment: Is there any way to use this with global-auto-revert-mode that doesn't lose the buffer's undo history?

Comment: This is not quite cross-platform. There is typically no *touch* on Windows.

Comment: On OSX I get `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument arrayp nil)
  replace-regexp-in-string("[^-0-9a-zA-Z_./\n]" "\\\\\\&" nil)
  shell-quote-argument(nil)
  (concat "touch " (shell-quote-argument (buffer-file-name)))
  (shell-command (concat "touch " (shell-quote-argument (buffer-file-name))))`

Answer (score 6):

Here is a pure emacs way to do it:

```
(defun touch-file ()
  "Force modification of current file, unless already modified."
  (interactive)
  (if (and (verify-visited-file-modtime (current-buffer))
           (not (buffer-modified-p)))
      (progn
        (set-buffer-modified-p t)
        (save-buffer 0))))
```

Comment: I like the "pure" elisp solution that doesn't require calling out to the shell, but does this approach just change the timestamp, or write the entire buffer to the file? Even dired-mode's touch command calls out to the shell to invoke the touch command. What we really need is an elisp function that calls utime() in C from the Emacs process.

Comment: @GregMattes - it basically does the equivalent of "modifying" the buffer and then saving it (without actually change the buffer contents).

Comment: Yeah, exactly. That could cause a lot of I/O if many files are being touched because the entire contents are being saved. For example, the question asker is interested in touching files to force testing. I could imagine that he might write some elisp to automatically touch a set of files, possibly a large set of files. So writing the whole file instead of just mutating the mtime in the inode might be very significant. I'm not saying your approach is wrong. In fact, it's really nice to have it all in platform-independent elisp without invoking an external shell command.

Comment: You also generate spurious backup files if you always back-up on save.  Touch is preferable.

Comment: @event_jr - good point.  updated so that it doesn't cause new backup versions to be generated.

Comment: Thanks for this @jtahlborn. I'm sticking with the touch solution so the file doesn't actually get written, but neat nonetheless.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe more keystrokes than a custom function, but you can do this out the box with `C-u M-~` then `C-x C-s`.

`M-~` is bound by default to `not-modified`, which clears the buffer's modification flag, unless you call it with an argument (`C-u` prefix), in which case it does the opposite.  Then just save the buffer.

Comment: Cool tip, same comments as on @jtahlborn's answer

Comment: @spike, I noticed that comment after posting, and I agree, touch is better.

Answer (score 3):

I do it like this: insert a space, end then I delete the space again and save. This changes the mtime.

Comment: yea, that's what I'm doing too, but there's got to be an emacs way

Comment: yeah, that's pretty much what I do too, but I wrote a lisp function that will help you (see my answer to this question).

Answer (score 2):

8 years later, the useful "f" library in melpa provides f-touch.

See: https://github.com/rejeep/f.el